# NMAKIT uses deprecated UIWebView - possibly in MDSKUI 2.1.2

Tags: here-api

I submitted an update to the app store today and received the warning Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs

I searched my app and found that I do not use a UiWebView.
Is the UiWebView used in Here SDK 3.12 or the MSDKUI 2.1.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sources of NMAKit does not contain any reference to UIWebView. However, I found at least one internal third-party dependency, which contains such reference.

3.13.2 version is planned to be released next week. Will let you know, if quick fix has been found and included in 3.13.2 or in next HERE SDK releases.

UPDATE:

HERE SDK 3.13.3 includes fixes for UIWebView warning and is available now.

HEREMapsUI (MSDKUI) still depends on 3.12. Please wait for the next release. Integration is not public yet, once available it will be announced on the [MSDKUI release page](https://github.com/heremaps/msdkui-ios/releases).

Comment: Unfortunately it is too late to include the fix in 3.13.2. It is planned to be added in 3.13.3, which will be released in 1,5 month. 
Thanks for reporting the issue!

Answer (score 1):

MSDKUI 2.1.2 does not have any reference to the UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

I found the UIWebView usage in NMAKIT
From terminal I changed directory to the latest Archive, e.g.

```
cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/<date>/myapp.xcarchive/Products/Applications/myapp.app
```

Then used nm:

```
nm GuideMeToHERE | grep UIWeb
for framework in Frameworks/*.framework; do
  fname=$(basename $framework .framework)
  echo $fname
  nm $framework/$fname | grep UIWeb
done
```

The output I got was:

```
NMAKit
                 U _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIWebView
```